# Google Team Drive: Not able to see Team Drives option for External user

Tags: javascript, sdk, google-drive-api, google-picker, google-drive-shared-drive

I have integrated Enabling Team Drive in File picker for Drive.
But I am not able to see the Team Drive tab in Invited user's account.

```
var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                    .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.SUPPORT_TEAM_DRIVES)
                    .addView(new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS)
                        .setEnableTeamDrives(true))
                    .addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS)
                    .setOAuthToken(accessToken)
                    .setAppId(clientId)
                    .setCallback(angular.bind(this, pickerCallback, filesSelectedCallback))
                    .build();
 picker.setVisible(true);
```

With this snippet **I am able to get Team Drives in Owner's account.**

[image]

Now I have invited another user(Not a G Suite member) to join Team drive. And opening the File picekr from invited user's account. **But I am not able to get the Team Drives in Invited user's account.**

[image]

What is missing here?
Do I need to enable something from Developer account?

Comment: Yes, you have to. Upon checking the [Picker API Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#appreqs) you need to create a project in the Google API Console, enable the API, and create credentials.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot Yes I already did that. That is why I am able to get those Team Drive and File details.